# Opening and closing positions at market price in pinescript not really working as expected?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have a pinescript strategy and i am trying to do short and long positions at the time of the indicator but I cannot understand why my previous position it.s not closing..
Integrated with binance webhooks.
For example:

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Bollinger bands [strategy]", overlay=true)

...
//code
...

// Submit entry orders
if positive
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long)

if negative
    strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short)
```

I have tried the following:

```
// Submit entry orders

if positive
    if strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.close_all()
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long)

if negative
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.close_all()
    strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short)
```

also tried with strategy.close("BUY") strategy.close("SELL")

My logic would be open position ->  close position -> open new position after the previous one is closed

The problem is that it.s not closing the previous position and opens the new one, for example: open long position 100$ -> opens short position 100$ and results in a 0.01 long/short position.

Any advice would be helpful! Thanks you!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your trade list?

Answer (score 0):

There is too little information to be clear about the situation you are describing.

Anyway in your first part, the position isn't closed because it doesn't have a command to do so.

Try this simple implementation for now:

```
// Submit entry orders
if positive
    strategy.close("SELL")
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long)
    
if negative
    strategy.close("BUY")
    strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short)
```

Please be more specific, add images, code and explain well your case.

Comment: To add to this answer: the opposite entry order always closes the current position. So the first iteration of the code in the question should work no matter what.